# Zoom plugin image error

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, frontend, elevatezoom

I'm developing a web application in java using jsf,I added the following plugin http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples  for zooming images. But when loading the page,when checking the page browser displays the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).elevateZoom is not a function
```

Code

```
  <h:outputScript library="resources" name="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" >
   </h:outputScript>
<h:outputScript library="resources" name="js/jquery.elevateZoom-
3.0.8.min.js"></h:outputScript>
 <h:outputScript library="resources" name="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    </h:outputScript>

             $(document).ready (function () {
             $("#img_01").elevateZoom({easing : true});
             });

<h:graphicImage library="resources" name="imagens/bermudas/lacoste.jpg" 
id="img_01" width="400px" height= "400px"  />
```

[image]

UPDATE

I put the breakpoint at the closing of `$ (document) .ready (function () {
 });`
But the breakpoint stops at `$ ("# img_01"). ElevateZoom ({easing: true});`

Comment: Debug in the browser developer tool. Check network traffic. 404's?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: In most browsers, press F12 and go to the console.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp

Comment: My answer would have been 'use google' ;- And you should have done the same in your other question (using the developer tools to debug)

Comment: I updated the question and put what happened when I debugged the code

Comment: I looked google dude and tested all possible answers to this error but it did not work